# PowerShell - PSObject properties becoming sets with the name of the next property appended to the collection

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a simple object in PowerShell that has four values. A boolean, two strings, and an integer. The problem is that if I call this function:

```
function New-ResultObject($Status, $Function, $Message, $Priority)
    {   

         return New-Object psobject -property  @{
                                                Status = $Status; `
                                                Function = $Function; `
                                                Message = $Message; `
                                                Priority = $Priority
                                                }

    }
```

Called this way:

```
$object= New-ResultObject -Status $false,`
                                    -Function "FunctionName",`
                                    -Message "This is the message",`
                                    -Priority 2
```

Then do a `$object | select *` I get this as a result:

```
$object.Function = {FunctionName, -Status}
$object.Status = {False, -Function} 
$object.Priority = 2
$object.Message = {This is the message, -Priority}
```

Instead of what I expected to be:

```
$object.Function = FunctionName
$object.Status = False 
$object.Priority = 2
$object.Message = This is the message
```

I have tried doing an Add-Member approach with each property on its' own line, but it still results in the same object, where the property name is added as a second value to the initial property. What am I missing?

Comment: You define parameter with commas, you do not call with commas. Should be spaces 
`$serverIsAvailable = New-ResultObject -Status $false -Function "FunctionName" -Message "This is the message" -Priority 2`

Comment: Just adding to this - powershell uses commas to define arrays, so you're effectively passing `-Status ($false,"-Message")`. A good way to catch weird stuff like this is to set typed parameters like `function foo { [bool]$Status, [int]$priority }`

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! I am just beginning with PowerShell and along the way to getting to this solution I was getting an error when trying to strongly type my parameters. The [string]s worked but the [bool] did not and now I understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common pitfall. You define the parameters as a comma delimited list but you call them space delimited.

```
$object= New-ResultObject -Status $false -Function "FunctionName" -Message "This is the message" -Priority 2
```

Also, I must implore you to stop using the backtick newline escaping trick. Instead you can use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1).

```
$params = @{
    Status   = $false
    Function = "FunctionName"
    Message  = "This is the message"
    Priority = 2
}

$object = New-ResultObject @params
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer). If you want to post an answer I can accept it. Otherwise, this was the issue, commas are not needed for multiple parameters and were causing the parameter tags to be passed in as multiple parts to the loosely-typed function parameters.

Here is a working example:

```
$object= New-ResultObject -Status $false `
                                -Function "FunctionName" `
                                -Message "This is the message" `
                                -Priority 2
```